# Version control for prose

Tags: git, version-control, text

It seems that someone has must have done this already, but I cannot find the end product I'm looking for.

Using a version control system for text is laborious. You need newline characters at the end of each sentence, and even in the midst of long sentences. Looking at the git source, it seems that by changing a few routines that check for `'\n'`, it should be possible to have git (or any other version control system) match `'\n'` or the pattern `'\\.\s'`. It is, however, a task that needs to be done meticulously, or I can see things breaking pretty badly.

Does anyone know someone that has already done this? Or any other alternatives?

Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest you to use MediaWiki for this. It does this kind of service (versioning prose, I mean) like a charm. It is a PHP application, for sure, but it is worth the work.

Comment: git works for prose. git doesn't require short lines or extra line breaks where you wouldn't have them naturally.

Comment: Is your concern displaying clean diffs, or having efficient compression? Git should be fine on the latter. It can also do word diffs, which would take care of a lot of your issues there, and it can even pass off diffs to an external difftool if you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any version control system should be able to handle prose.  The question is how efficiently it can do so.

The `git diff` command uses something like `diff -u` to display the differences between two versions of a file.  If the file consists of text with very long lines (i.e., many characters between `'\n'` characters), then it might have some difficulty displaying the differences meaningfully; it might show two 5000-character lines with only a single character change.

But that doesn't necessarily imply that that's how `git` *stores* the files.  I'm not intimately familiar with git's internal storage format, but my understanding is that it does reasonably well with binary files, which could have many megabytes of data with no `'\n'` characters.

Note that some older version control systems (SCCS, RCS) probably do store differences between versions on a line-by-line basis.  But even for such systems, *at worst* you'd be storing a full copy of each version plus some overhead.  The system should still be able to work properly.

Note that `git diff --word-diff` should at least partially work around the problem of comparing versions.

Comment: Just as a note about the very useful `git diff --word-diff` - this feature was added in v1.7.2, but in earlier versions you can use `git diff --color-words`.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses. I found Jefromi's comment particularly useful, and in conjunction with Keith's answer, I think I understand what I want. I don't care how git does the diff and the storage, I want it to be smart in displaying the diffs. If the source text is not hard-wrapped (no line breaks in the source), then I want each sentence (period-delimited) to be treated as a separate unit for diff display.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for advice as well as to @MarkLongair this makes my diffing to prose so much easier. I have just put up with this shit for years without realizing there was a solution.